# jquery or javascript to check which div is open

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My page has got many divs which internal contains menus. After auto refresh it coming back to home page. i want to know before auto refresh which div was visible or shown so that after auto refresh i can again openup the same div.

Comment: Where will you store the data? Client side data will be wiped unless you are planning to store it in a cookie. 

You can write a javascript function which check all the div using the getTagName() function and see the visibility/Height/Left value for open state

    Or two classes for open and close state and attach the div id to the openstate class in jquery

Comment: @abhilash Cherukat- I am having a JSF application. I cnt check all the div using the getTagName() as there are many divs . I need to know on which div user was last before autorefresh happened

Answer (score 0):

You can store all div's display status in php code/database/session..so that whenever page get refreshed it will pull out divs status from db or session and will show expected result.

Comment: I am having a JSF application. I cnt check all the div using the getTagName(). I need to know on which div user was last before autorefresh.